# MySQL syntax query on aggregation

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table called TICKET with columns FLIGHTNUMBER and INSURED. INSURED has only 0 or 1 values. FLIGHTNUMBER has duplicates. I wanted to get the FLIGHTNUMBER with the max number of 1s in INSURED. Here's what I tried:

```
SELECT FLIGHTNUMBER 
FROM (SELECT FLIGHTNUMBER,SUM(INSURED) AS INSURANCE_COUNT 
      FROM TICKET 
      GROUP BY TICKET.FLIGHTNUMBER) AS OUT2 
WHERE OUT2.INSURANCE_COUNT = MAX(INSURANCE_COUNT) ;
```

AND

```
SELECT FLIGHTNUMBER 
FROM (SELECT FLIGHTNUMBER,SUM(INSURED) AS INSURANCE_COUNT 
      FROM TICKET 
      GROUP BY TICKET.FLIGHTNUMBER 
      HAVING INSURANCE_COUNT = MAX(SUM(INSURED))) AS OUT2;
```

But both are causing errors. Could you please tell me the correct syntax. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there are multiple flights that are tied for the max, do you need to get all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one doesn't work because you can't use an aggregation function in a `WHERE` clause. Aggregation doesn't happen until after all the rows are selected, and `WHERE` is used to select the rows, so there's a chicken-and-egg problem.

The second doesn't work because you can't nest aggregation functions.

You don't need to calculate `MAX(INSURANCE_COUNT)`. Just order the query and take the first one.

```
SELECT flightnumber
FROM (SELECT flightnumber, SUM(INSURED) AS insurance_count
      FROM ticket
      GROUP BY flightnumber) AS out2
ORDER BY insurance_count DESC
LIMIT 1
```

You don't even need `insurance_count` in the `SELECT` list, so you don't need to wrap it in a subquery to get rid of it.

```
SELECT flightnumber
FROM ticket
GROUP BY flightnumber
ORDER BY SUM(insured) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

However, if there are multiple flights that are tied for the max, this will just return one of them. If you need to get all of them, you need to write a subquery that gets the max, and join with that.

```
SELECT flightnumber
FROM (SELECT flightnumber, SUM(insured) AS insurance_count
      FROM ticket
      GROUP BY flightnumber) AS out2
JOIN (SELECT SUM(insured) AS max_insurance_count
      FROM ticket
      GROUP BY flightnumber
      ORDER BY max_insurance_count DESC
      LIMIT 1) AS out3
ON out2.insurance_count = out3.max_insurance_count
```

Comment: It is also worth noting that, unless the presence of insurance_count in the result is an issue, a subquery is not actually needed. `GROUP BY flightnumber ORDER BY insurance_count DESC LIMIT 1` would work as well.

Comment: @Uueerdo I did even better.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I forget the aggregate doesn't actually have to be in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
SELECT flightnumber, SUM(insured) AS insured_count 
FROM ticket 
GROUP BY flightnumber 
ORDER BY insured_count DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

This is just a `SUM` aggregation on the `insured` column, grouped by `flightnumber`, and sorted on the `insured_count` in descending order. We only keep the first result.

This doesn't consider what would happen if two flightnumbers had the same max insured count. You could break ties with a second `ORDER BY` field, or run another outer query.

If you had a `flightnumber` table you could just update its `insured_count` field with a `SUM()` every time you modify the `ticket` table. That would be more efficient if you're running this report very often, the `ticket` table ends up with a lot of rows, and most of the rows aren't changing after a flight is complete.